# Can you find previously generated random numbers using java.util.Random?

Tags: java, random

Is it possible to find previously generated random numbers using `java.util.Random`?

---

I found information at [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/java_util_random_algorithm.shtml#.VeU1y_lViko) website, it indicates that it uses a [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in the format

number<sub>i+1</sub> = (a * number<sub>i</sub> + c) mod 2<sup>48</sup>

where the first value of number is seed and is simply incremented by one every time nextInt (or somthing similar) is called

Does anyone have any more information on how it is generated? or what the offset values are?

Edit: I found [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java) source code from the openjdk

Comment: You can just save the numbers in a list or something. I don't think the class saves some sort of state that you can access.

Comment: well, it is possible to find the previous generated random number provided you know the exact time in nano second when the previous number is generated. The source code already explain it I believe ;)

Comment: @kucing_terbang, default seed for `new Random()` is not just `nanoTime()`, it's trickier, so knowing nano second is not enough.

Comment: As for "how it is generated", I think the javadoc says it well enough: See [Random.setSeed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed%28long%29) and especially [Random.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next%28int%29)

Comment: @kucing_terbang The *time* the previous number was generated has **no** influence on the number. The pseudo-generated random numbers depend on a seed value, which is updated on each call, so the *number of calls* since an initial seed was obtained (implicit or explicit) matter, not *when* the last call was made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, you can get the previous `Random` values without storing them (and without knowing the original seed of the `Random` object like @Andreas suggests). Here's the proof-of-concept code. It supports reverting the `nextLong()` calls only, but it's possible to revert other calls as well.

```
public class InvRand {
    private static final long addend = 0xBL;
    private static final long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
    private static final long invMultiplier = 0xDFE05BCB1365L;
    private static final long mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL;

    private long seed;

    public InvRand(Random r) {
        seed = prevSeed(replicateSeed(r.nextLong()));
    }

    public long prevLong() {
        seed = prevSeed(seed);
        long b1 = seed >>> 16;
        seed = prevSeed(seed);
        long b2 = seed >>> 16;
        return (b2 << 32) + b1;
    }

    static long replicateSeed(long nextLong) {
        int nextM = (int)(nextLong & 0xFFFFFFFF);
        int nextN = (int)((nextLong - nextM) >> 32);

        long upperMOf48Mask = 0xFFFFFFFF0000L;

        long oldSeedUpperN = ((long)nextN << 16) & mask;
        long newSeedUpperM = ((long)nextM << 16) & mask;

        for (long oldSeed = oldSeedUpperN; oldSeed <= (oldSeedUpperN | 0xFFFF); 
                  oldSeed++) {
            long newSeed = (oldSeed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
            if ((newSeed & upperMOf48Mask) == newSeedUpperM) {
                return newSeed;
            }
        }
        throw new InternalError();
    }

    static long prevSeed(long seed) {
        return ((seed - addend) * invMultiplier) & mask;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.println("next: " + Long.toHexString(rand.nextLong()));
    }
    InvRand ir = new InvRand(rand);
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.println("prev: "+Long.toHexString(ir.prevLong()));
    }
}
```

Typical output:

```
next: 76c8febd3eab0fd8
next: 19ea99b87b9c118e
next: 2d69d148285ac86e
next: f466d00f770361e7
next: ca069823ec343ea2
next: f570a154be288a23
next: 3f2f3844ad48b1ea
next: d79ed82cd2e927e
next: 97ffcecf7d9a5b0a
next: d4e1a218dea3fc6f
next: c54e390e8f9486fe
next: 670052e4c52b230
next: ed13a7adac2ffc1c
next: f4e41dc7ada0ea7d
next: 56ffb122ab160d7a
next: cd7ecd6d1236049b
next: ce0597694257008c
next: d32d6ef8c142a09b
next: 2e8bb4f2356ea912
next: f5bf0eb275fb77df
prev: f5bf0eb275fb77df // note numbers are going backwards now
prev: 2e8bb4f2356ea912
prev: d32d6ef9c142a09b
prev: ce0597694257008c
prev: cd7ecd6d1236049b
prev: 56ffb123ab160d7a
prev: f4e41dc8ada0ea7d
prev: ed13a7aeac2ffc1c
prev: 670052e4c52b230
prev: c54e390f8f9486fe
prev: d4e1a219dea3fc6f
prev: 97ffcecf7d9a5b0a
prev: d79ed83cd2e927e
prev: 3f2f3845ad48b1ea
prev: f570a155be288a23
prev: ca069824ec343ea2
prev: f466d00f770361e7
prev: 2d69d148285ac86e
prev: 19ea99b87b9c118e
prev: 76c8febd3eab0fd8
```

There are two problems here. First is to replicate the random seed by `nextLong` value. This part (`replicateSeed`) is based on [this code](https://github.com/fta2012/ReplicatedRandom/blob/master/ReplicatedRandom.java#L15) from GitHub. Next problem is to invert the seed calculation formula, so we can change the seed from the current to the previous. Current OpenJDK nextseed formula is:

```
nextseed = (oldseed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
```

So it's just addition and multiplication in ring of integers modulo 2^48. Both operations are inversible. For addition you can just subtract in the same ring. For multiplication you have to calculate the inverted multiplier, which can be done solving Diophantine equation `x*0x5DEECE66DL+y*0x1000000000000L = 1`. Solving it you get `x = 0xDFE05BCB1365L` (select the solution which fits the ring). So to inverse the multiplication you just need to multiply by `0xDFE05BCB1365L`.

Comment: @MarkOmo, you're welcome. I already desperately thought that nobody is interested in my research :-) It took quite a time to gather all the pieces together to the working code.

Comment: No I really appreciate the effort you put into it, I am just having truble printing the seed, I was trying to use "prevSeed(replicateSeed(rand.nextLomg()))" to print a seed I manually set but it does not work, nor does simply creating another Random with the generated seed. My end goal is to replacate nextInt calls, I thought resetting the seed was a good way of doing that.

Comment: @MarkOmo, if you want to create another `Random` with the same seed value, you should use `new Random(prevSeed(replicateSeed(rand.nextLong()))) ^ 0x5DEECE66DL);` There's `Random.initialScramble` method which XORs the supplied seed with the multiplier, so you should XOR it again to revert this operation.

Comment: Just tried it out: `long seed;
  seed = 2521L;
  Random rand = new Random(seed);
  System.out.println("next: " + Long.toHexString(rand.nextLong()));
  Random rand2 = new Random(InvRand.prevSeed(InvRand.replicateSeed(rand.nextLong())) ^ 0x5DEECE66DL);
  System.out.println("next: " + Long.toHexString(rand2.nextLong()));` Output is next: f197dc2ce142b839 next: 1b80d642e58bafd as opposed to the expected same values, I noticed the seed is incriminated twice for long could that be the problem?

Comment: @MarkOmo, I see. First, the original `rand` state changes when you call `nextLong()` to replicate the seed, so you have to roll-back it as well. Second, `nextLong()` changes the seed twice. Thus you need to call `prevSeed` 4 times: `Random rand2 = new Random(InvRand.prevSeed(InvRand.prevSeed(InvRand.prevSeed(InvRand.prevSeed(InvRand.replicateSeed(rand.nextLong()))))) ^ 0x5DEECE66DL);`

Comment: thanks so much for your help! want to incorporate that into your anwser so others can learn from my silly mistakes?

Comment: If you remove **toHexString** method you will see that the numbers are different. **toHexString** generate a hash of a unsigned number and for some reason it works in your algorithm

Comment: The seeds generated by InvRand are pretty different as well

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly you mean by the question, the answer is **yes**.

You *can* re-generate ("find") the same sequence of random numbers, *if* you supply a seed value, either on the constructor (`new Random(seed)`) or by using `setSeed(seed)`.

Since the random numbers are pseudo-generated, the numbers generated after a specified seed will always be the same.

*Proof*

```
long seed = 54321;

Random r = new Random(seed);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print(r.nextInt(1000) + " ");
System.out.println();

r.setSeed(seed);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print(r.nextInt(1000) + " ");
System.out.println();
```

*Output*

```
928 451 642 402 522 773 977 704 893 115 
928 451 642 402 522 773 977 704 893 115
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have any more information on how it is generated?

From Java doc of [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class:

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of pseudorandom
>   numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a
>   linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer
>   Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.2.1.)

Now next part is:

> Is it possible to find previously generated random numbers using
>   java.util.Random?

The algorithms implemented by class Random use a protected utility method that on each invocation can supply up to 32 pseudorandomly generated bits. So answer is perhaps **No** but you can keep them in a list if you want to.